# findOne returns null but it should not (mongoDB)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm just asking myself why my template returns null when it shouldn't.

This is my findOne :

```
await this.findOne({name}, async (template) => {
    console.log(template);
    if (template) return cb(new Error('Template already exists'));
```

And I'm sure that it should returns me the error Template already exists, because the document with this name exists in my DB.

Someone know why?

Comment: why do you have await in front when you are providing a callback? Also, why do you gave async in front of you callback function?

Comment: I'm quite new to nodeJs (4-5 month), but a NodeJs developer told me to do that, so i don't really know :/
And I want to say that it's just a part of a function that's why there is an await

Comment: I have added a answer. let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `.exec()` at the end to get the promise and use await to get the value like this

```
const template = await this.findOne({name}).exec();
// do something here with template
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn't know .exec(), it works now ;)

And if I add err in my callback, it works too